# How to add headers for an Ionic List?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic list like following:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKorF.png

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="x in names|orderBy:'order_id'">
        {{ x.order_id + ', ' + x.table_id+', '+x.name+', '+x.phone+', '+x.address+', '+x.remark+', '+changTimetoString(x.ctime)}}
        <button onclick="myFunction()">点击这里</button>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

I want to add headers for each column, how can I achieve that? thanks.

Comment: Try to implement by adding a extra <ion-item> tag, Ex:                                   <ion-item >
       order_id,table_id,name,address,remark,ctime
 </ion-item>

Comment: @Muhsin, thanks. now I got http://i.imgur.com/fsdIj2b.png (with a little alignment flaw), if it can be better and I want a table style looks like this http://i.imgur.com/FKZd1dA.png, I don't know whether it's possible to achive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to want to use the [ion grid](http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/using-the-grid/) rather than a list for this. here is a example from a project I made that does what I think you are trying to do:

```
<div class="list">
            <div  style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" class="item">
                <div class="row" style="background-color:#284f9a !important; color: white !important;">
                    <div class="col left" >
                        Driver:
                    </div>
                    <div class="col center" ng-click="reverse=!reverse; data.metric = 'MPG'">
                        MPG
                        <i class="icon" ng-class="{'ion-arrow-down-b': reverse == true && data.metric == 'MPG', 'ion-arrow-up-b': reverse == false && data.metric == 'MPG'}"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col right" ng-click="reverse=!reverse; data.metric = 'Miles'">
                        Miles
                        <i class="icon" ng-class="{'ion-arrow-down-b': reverse == true && data.metric == 'Miles', 'ion-arrow-up-b': reverse == false && data.metric == 'Miles'}"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" ng-repeat="item in leaderboardData | orderBy:data.metric:reverse">
                    <div class="col left">
                        {{item.Driver}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col center">
                        {{item.MPG}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="col right">
                        {{item.Miles}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Then for the alternating row colors add this css:

```
.row:nth-child(odd) {

    background-color: #CCC;

}

.row:nth-child(even) {

    background-color: white;

}
```

looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a try~

Comment: when I use ion grid, I find it can not scroll, how to solve that?

Comment: Just put the grid inside a ion-content

Answer (score 1):

You can use either Ionic Grid System, or you can use Ionic List Dividers.

I think the grid will solve you problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a try~